# RSS php reader with select (option) box

Tags: php, xml, rss

I create this PHP file. But this read only one link. How can I add the other two? The selection box read on page only one link ... http://www.kurir.rs/rss/vesti/"
http://www.blic.rs/rss/IT

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <select name="rss">
        <option value="http://www.kurir.rs/rss/vesti/">Kurir</option>
        <option value="http://www.blic.rs/rss/IT">Blic</option>
        <option value="http://www.b92.net/info/rss/tehnopolis.xml">B92</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Select" />
</form>

<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://www.b92.net/info/rss/tehnopolis.xml');

$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 5;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
}
```

?>

Comment: I have only this.

Comment: I see no PHP here. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't have php. I need to do this assignment for tomorrow but don't know how. Do you know for some site where I can see an example for this or you can help me to make php file?

Comment: There are tons of online tutorials to get you started. It doesn't seem like you've put any effort into this at all.

Comment: This php file is only for pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer, you need to use what is posted from your form to load the page. So something like this:

```
$rss_url = isset($_REQUEST['rss']) ? $_REQUEST['rss'] : 'http://www.b92.net/info/rss/tehnopolis.xml';
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load( $rss_url );
```

I even threw some validation in there to check if `$_REQUEST['rss']` is set.

Is this the best way to do this? no. You would need to further validate your input so people can post something unexpected. Also using POST, may be unnecessary for this. GET might work just fine. But for this exercise, it will work.

Also, if you wanted the option box to show the selected url:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <select name="rss">


<?php
$selection = array (
    'Kurir' => 'http://www.kurir.rs/rss/vesti/', 
    'Blic' => 'http://www.blic.rs/rss/IT', 
    'B92' => 'http://www.b92.net/info/rss/tehnopolis.xml' );

foreach ($selection as $title => $url) {
    if(! empty($_REQUEST) and isset($_REQUEST['rss']) and $_REQUEST['rss'] == $url ){
        $selected = 'selected';       
    } else {
        $selected = '';
    }
    print'<option value="'.$url.'" '.$selected.'>'.$title.'</option>';
    print "\n";
}


?>

    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Select" />
</form>

<?php
$rss_url = isset($_REQUEST['rss']) ? $_REQUEST['rss'] : 'http://www.b92.net/info/rss/tehnopolis.xml';
print $rss_url;
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you! Working great except the box. A box display only the first title does not change when loading. It's only for exercise, still learning...

Comment: I updated the solution to include having the box selected when changed. Its not the most elegant solution. But it will do.

Comment: Also, please mark this answer as the solution. I like those sweet stack overflow points.

Comment: Thank you! That's great!